# About entity framework database generation power pack

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, code-generation

I've tried using this pack to do database migration after I changed the EF edmx file.
But I always receive following error:

```
Creating [sg].[Addresses]...
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named 'Addresses' in the database.
** An error was encountered during execution of batch. Exiting.
```

The addresses table is in database for sure, because this is a migration script. I selected "Generate Migration T-SQL.xaml (VS)" strategy for generating database. How come the script does not address this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should still be in a separate, new database that you are generating the... well... *new database*. The fact that it is a migration just means that existing data/metadata is being taken into account to (possibly) be moved. It does not mean it alters the existing database.

Comment: Can't believe that, this sort of features are already sat on django for years now.

Comment: It has nothing to do with features. It has to do with what option you chose. 'Migration' is 'moving'.